# wish to delete the word but \b seems not working

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    x,y=pyautogui.position()
    position=str(x)+','+str(y)
    print(position,end='')
    print('\b'*len(position),end='')
```

i hope it could print out the position of my mouse and delete it before showing the next one, so i will only see one position on the program.
however, the \b don't delete the position.
the program just keep print a new position without delete the previous one, which makes me hard to read
how should i change my program to let it delete the previous position
thank you

Answer (score 0):

in shell \b is not taken as backspace
need to run cmd and it will work fine